# Preventing users to access class fields

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing a DLL using C# 4.0 which will be used by several C# .NET based desktop applications (let's call them AppA and AppB). It is required that AppA will be able to use certain class' selected fields/properties/functions that won't be even available to AppB. My approach was to use `internal` modifier for those properties and grant access to AppA by specifying AppA's assembly name in `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute of the DLL. But `internal` modifier is also required in some properties which will be accessed in other parts of the DLL but not to be accessed by AppA. Now it appears that there are too many `internal`s which are exposed to AppA which shouldn't be accessible by AppA.

In other words, consider the following properties:

```
class A
{
    internal int ReallyInternal {get; set;}
    internal int AppAInternal {get; set;}
}
```

If I use `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute for AppA, then both `ReallyInternal` and `AppAInternal` properties will be exposed to AppA - where as `ReallyInternal` shouldn't be exposed to AppA.

How to solve this? Is there any other way to implement this scenario?

**Background**

Before going to `InternalsVisibleTo` approach we thought of other ways, like having different interfaces etc. The class library I'm writing will be used by multiple applications. I wanted to have the interface same across applications.

Consider `TT4` as a class in the DLL. It's properties will be populated from a physical device via serial communication.

```
TT4 tt4 = new TT4();
// Some code to populate tt4 object

MessageBox.Show(tt4.SerialNumber);
tt4.SerialNumber = "123";
```

Because `tt4` object will represent a physical device, not all of its properties should be modifiable by all applications. This won't make sense and if we allow this then any application can change the serial number of the device. (Yes, SerialNumber can be written back to the device).

We've only one application (here AppA for example) which will be able to set and change the SerialNumber. Other applications shouldn't do that. It's prevented by making SerialNumber's setter as `internal` and granting permission to AppA by `InternalsVisibleTo`.

Please note that providing the library with two classes is not the solution. Say, I've implemented two classes for `TT4` - `TT4` (cannot write SerialNumber) and `TT4Super` (can write SerialNumber). When the DLL will be given to clients, they can still see `TT4Super` and use that.

I'm not the developer of other applications and I have no control of them.

Comment: Is this a security concern, or an encapsulation concern? Also, why not provide different interfaces that have different levels of access, based on what the user needs?

Comment: I'd also see if you can avoid internal properties altogether.

Comment: I think a different approach might be more suitable. "It is required that AppA will be able to use certain class' selected fields/properties/functions that won't be even available to AppB." <-- Can you explain the rationale behind this?

Comment: I think features like `InternalsVisibleTo` should be used with great prudence. There's almost always a better way to achieve what you are trying to do. Perhaps if you could describe that to us instead, we could propose a solution to that.

Comment: @siride: I've added background information which should answer your question. And it's encapsulation concern.

Comment: @OJRaqueño: Please check the background information which I just added.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do that would be to extract all the members that should be exposed to AppA to an abstract class (or a parent class in general) and make them `protected internal`. To access them from AppA it would have to inherit from the abstract class. For instance

```
public abstract class ParentA
{
    internal int ReallyInternal {get; set;}
    protected internal int AppAInternal {get; set;}
}
```

And AppA accesses it the following way:

```
internal class AinAppA : ParentA
{
    internal AinAppA()
    {
        this.AppAInternal = 1; // can access parents protected members
        // this.ReallyInternal = 2; // but pure internal members are not visible
    }
}
```

As a side note, `InternalsVisibleTo` is not meant to be an access modifier. It's main purpose is to make unit testing easier not to enable communication between production assemblies.

Comment: `InternalsVisibleTo` is for unit testing? Are you sure? It does put something similar to a dependency on the unit test assembly, at least during the build. Not something I like in my production assemblies.

Comment: That's fairly popular use. Will try to find some good references to support that.

Comment: It also happens to be an awful way to program as it encourages you to break Listkov.

Comment: Agree with @Aron. To me, `internal` on a member says that the class does too much or should be part of another class, or should be passed around separately. In my own projects, I've never or only rarely had to use `internal` on anything other than classes, where I use it to say that the class is not part of the public API of a library.

Comment: `protected internal` doesn't mean `protected` AND `internal`. It means `protected` OR `internal`. In other words, that modifier allows anyone to use it as long as they subclass `ParentA`. On the other hand, I don't think the subclassing idea would work in any case because OP is looking for a way to expose properties on his DLL's objects.

Answer (score 1):

Are you mostly concerned that the designers of AppB are going to do something malicious with your DLL, or that you simply want to prevent them from doing something inadvertently? Making your members `internal` won't really prevent someone from doing harm via reflection if they want to.

One (admittedly not great) approach you could use is to make these members public, but prevent anyone except AppA from using them, by checking the calling assembly:

```c#
private void VerifyCaller(Assembly a)
{
    if (a == Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()) { return; }

    var name = a.GetName();
    if(name.Name == "AppA" && name.GetPublicKey() == appAPublicKey) { return; }

    throw new InvalidOperationException("You can't access this");
}

private string _serialNumber;
public string SerialNumber
{
    get { return _serialNumber; }
    set
    {
        VerifyCaller(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
        _serialNumber = value;
    }
}
```

this should at least prevent anyone from easily using reflection to circumvent your defenses.

Comment: I want to prevent AppB developers from doing something inadvertently. How can they access internals using Reflection?